# order of execution in useEffect clean up

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return history.replace({
      pathname: "path/A",
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.replace({
      pathname: "path/B",
    });
  }, []);
```

When the component unmounts, what will be the URL? What determines the order of execution of the above 2 `useEffect`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the nature of you passing no `deps`; both of these `useEffect`s will only be rendered on component mount. Therefore, the result is (and always will be) `"path/B"`.

If you wanted it to change on component unmount, you'd need to add a `return` function to one of them.

```
useEffect(() => {
    history.replace({ pathname: "path/B" });
    return () => history.replace({ pathname: "path/B" });
}, []);
```

Comment: I forgot the return keyword in my post. I made an edit.

Comment: @free_lions_n_tigers_from_cages Since JavaScript is inherently a _top-to-bottom_ language, `B` will be the result.